# SqlDataReader GetValue taking a lot of time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an MSSQL query. If I run it in SSMS - it returns the result set in a timely manner (below 10 seconds) - 1012 rows.

In C#, using a SqlDataReader, about every 7 or 8 rows, when calling GetValue, it takes about 8 seconds. It doesn't always happen for the same field (the result set has 48 fields in total). However, it's either a String or a Guid field.

I have other queries running in the same way (with lots of fields including String and Guid), returning 3000+ rows with absolutely no problem. The problematic query runs with no problem on 100+ other servers.

What could be causing this?

Below is a simplified version of the code, but it still behaves in the same way. Stopwatch is not in the production code, I've only added it for testing.

```
if ( aReader != null && !aReader.IsClosed && aReader.HasRows )
{
   while( aReader.Read())
   {
      for ( int iFieldIndex = 0; iFieldIndex < aReader.FieldCount; iFieldIndex++ )
      {
         Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
         object test = aReader.GetValue( iFieldIndex );
         s.Stop();
         // Every other 7 or 8 rows, s.ElapsedMilliseconds is >= 8000.
      }
   }
}
```

I have no exception handling inside the read block. The reader and command are properly disposed of. As I already mentioned - the same code works fine on 100+ other servers, using the same SQL query. This only happens on one machine.

Comment: This happened to me when my C# code was trying to convert the NULLs in some fields to dates, and it was throwing exceptions.  I was catching the exceptions so the program didn't crash, but it was running very slowly.  Is anything throwing an exception inside of your reading loop?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: It would help us if you could share some code.

Comment: If the same code/query runs fine on other servers - then the entry point to debugging would likely be the problematic server and not the code itself. Check up on server metrics. You might have network, memory or disk IO issues.

Comment: If you say `It doesn't always happen for the same field [...]. However, it's either a String or a Guid field.` what type is this column you want to access? If it is CHAR or VARCHAR (or whatever this is in MSSQL) then try to save the result from `GetValue()` in a string variable